# Invalid object name when I set a dbSet in the dbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to add a dbSet in the configuration of the dbContext:

```
internal class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
    internal DbSet<MyType1> DbSet1 { get; set; }
    internal DbSet<MyType2> DbSet2 { get; set; }
    internal DbSet<MyType3> DbSet3 { get; set; }
}
```

But when I try to do a query, I get the error that the object name DbSet3 is not valid.

```
return await _contexto.DbSet3
    .Where(x => x.Id== paramId)
    .ToListAsync();
```

But if I try to do the same kind of query with DbSet1 or DbSet2 I don't have any problem.

Thanks.

EDIT: I have realize that if I only change the type when I define the dbSet in this way, it works:

Why I get this problem with the third DbSet and not with the rest?

```
internal DbSet<MyType2> DbSet3 { get; set; }
```

I mean, if I change from MyType3 to MyType2, and I keep the name DbSet3 it works.

EDIT 2: The solution:

The problem was that in the configuration of the type, I made the mistake to indicate a different type with similar name. I did that:

```
internal class ConfigurationMyType3: IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyType4>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyType4> config)
    {
    }
}
```

So I should to change to this to make it work:

```
internal class ConfigurationMyType3: IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyType3>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyType3> config)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the actual table in the database, which corresponds to the `MyType3` entity, has the same name and a the schema is correct?

Comment: There is a mapping between the c# classes and the tables/column in the database.  You probably need to update the mapping by using migration.  Migration has two modes 1) Create 2) Update.

Comment: The problem was in the configuration, in IEntityTypeConfiguration. I was using a type that was similar name and I didn't realize. I add the details in the original post.